# Differences between low-and high-level languages using the Von Neumann model

Tags: programming-languages, difference, von-neumann

I'm confused by this textbook problem:

> Assembler is a low-level language, but Java and Python are high-level languages.
> Explain the difference with an example using the Von Neumann model. Choose either Java or Python.

I know the differences between low-level and high-level languages, but I'm having a really hard time figuring out a way to explain the differences using the Neumann model. I don't really see what the model has to do with low-or high-level languages? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Low-level languages take their fundamentals from the Von Neumann machine, so they are at a level very close to the machine. They are classified into machine language and assembly language. Also, the instructions are different on each computer, so they are difficult to program and are costly.
[image: Von Neumann Architecture]
High-level languages are based on Abstract MAchines. Whenever a high-level language is being used, an interpretation or translation process will be necessary, which helps to convert the programming language to machine language so that it can be executed.
[image: Abstract Machine]